# Anuglar 5 Kendo UI kendo-tabstrip-tab

Tags: angular5, kendo-tabstrip

I want to read div element dynamically while selecting tabs.

Note: I'm creating Multi-axis chart. That's why I'm using jquery chart.

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

html:

```
 <kendo-tabstrip (tabSelect)="ChartTabSelection($event)">
        <!-- FIRST TAB -->
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="' abc 123'" [selected]="true">
          <ng-template kendoTabContent>           
            <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
              <div #kendoChart1></div>
            </div>            
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
        <!-- SECOND TAB -->
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'abc 234'">
          <ng-template kendoTabContent>

            <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
              <div #kendoChart2></div>
            </div>           
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
      </kendo-tabstrip>
```

controller.ts

```
ChartTabSelection(data: any) {
        if (data.index === 0) {
 kendo.jQuery(this.component.kendoChart1.nativeElement).kendoChart({

});
        } else {
 kendo.jQuery(this.component.kendoChart2.nativeElement).kendoChart({

});
        }
  }
```

Comment: What type of object is `kendoChar1`? Try console logging that and posting the output here

Comment: Here object type is not important. I want ready div DOM.

Comment: The object is most definitely important because you're trying to grab the `nativeElement` property from it, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've fixed this issue with  setTimeout(() => {              kendo.jQuery(this.component.kendoChart2.nativeElement).kendoChart({  });  }, 100);

Comment: Sounds like a really terrible solution, you might want to try running this code later in the angular lifecycle instead of just using a random settimeout. Check out `ngAfterInitView` and maybe run the code inside that instead